# problem to link react app to nodejs server on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ubuntu, nginx

im hosting my react app to hostinger single host and my nodejs app to hostinger vps so my react app work normally in localhost but after build and host it cannot get any data from node server.
this is how i link with proxy:
 `{ "homepage": "https://cubexpro.net/", "version": "0.1.0", }, "devDependencies": { "@iconify/react": "^4.0.0", "node-sass": "^7.0.3" }, "proxy": "http://45.132.240.106" }`

im trying to add port to the link but nothing is working

Comment: I don't know how did you structure the projects, but I think you're trying to connect to a backend server, and you need to specify the URL of the backend somewhere, si you can use it later on axios/fetch/whatever. I suggest you to set the host URL of the backend in an environment variable or .env file, so when you build the project it uses the appropiate URL for that environment.

Comment: I already set the host url in .env file but I think because my vps URL use HTTP

Comment: Can you confirm that the nodejs backend is accessible from the internet? Like from your browser?

Comment: yeah it is accessible from the internet and from my localhost but when i build my reactjs app and host it it will be not accessible

Comment: If you can access the backend from the internet (ie your browser) then you reactjs frontend should reach it, because your react frontend will run on your browser. I suggest you to open your browser devtools, go to Network tab, open your react frontend and check where is it trying to connect